# Optimizing Django Many-To-Many Query with custom through table

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, many-to-many

I have 2 models:

```
class ModelA:
    fieldA = models.ManyToManyField(ModelB, through="CustomThroughTable")

    def foobar(self):
      return self.fieldA.through.objects.filter(fieldA=self)

class ModelB:
    whatever = models.CharField()
```

I want to implement a function in `ModelA` that would print out all the values of `fieldA` in the through table. The current implementation of the function `foobar` does what I need right now, but I figure it's rather inefficient. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think it is inefficient?

Comment: I used `debug_toolbar` to count the number of SQL queries made and it was way over the number of existing records, which led me to think this function is the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything inefficient about that query, you'll have to debug your problem more precisely.

That said, you can achieve the same thing more simply (and equally efficiently) by just using a related name on the through table.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    fieldA = models.ManyToManyField(ModelB, through="CustomThroughTable")

class ModelB(models.Model):
    whatever = models.CharField()

class CustomThroughTable(models.Model):
    modela = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, related_name="foobar")
    modelb = models.ForeignKey(ModelB)
```